# What were the details of the election fraud on the 1927 elections in Liberia?

Tags: africa, election

The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1927_Liberian_general_election) says that the voter turnout exceeded 1660% because the number of those who participated in the elections far exceeded the number of eligible voters. The election was recorded in the Guiness book as the most fraudulent in history.

Still, I feel that something should be behind this and not all is so simple. If the government just wanted to forge the elections, there is no reason to so blatantly break the basic arithmetics. Also, the elected president was completely legally impeached shortly afterwards (and not because of the election fraud), so it seems there was no strong cult of personality or dictatorship.
His opponent participated in later elections but again lost.

So, why such rigged election was mostly seen as legitimate?
Was it because the electoral commission explicitely made point of allowing more people to participate than was officially eligible (thus making the election more or less indicative of the true popular opinion) or there were other factors?

Comment: What did you find in the sources listed on the Wikipedia article?

Comment: @shoover is correct; I'd recommend this be closed as too basic pending an explanation of why [Academic Report on The Grass-roots of Conflict in Liberia](https://web.archive.org/web/20110716041012/http://www.senegambianews.com/article/Education/Education/Academic_Report_on_The_Grassroots_of_Conflict_in_Liberia/2151) and [LiberiaPastAndPresent.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20171120205806/http://www.liberiapastandpresent.org/1927ElectionsMF.htm) don't answer the question.